# Prevent a component rendering inside formik

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I want to disable the rendering of a component inside react.js formik library
here is an example of code structure I have currently

```
<formik 
  initialValue={{
    "show":false
  }}>
  return (
    <button name="showbtn" onclick={setFieldValue("show",true)}/>
     {values?.show ? 
     (
       <Text>Hello</Text>
     ) : 
    null}
    <Rerenderedcomponent />  //no prop passed here
  )
</formik>
```

And here is an example of my Rerendered component file

```
function Rerenderedcomponent() 
{
  const callingAPI = useCallback(()=>response,[])
}

export default React.memo(Rerenderedcomponent)
```

Now as I am clicking on the button(name `showbtn`) formik "show" field value is getting updated but my component(`Rerenderedcomponent`) is also getting rerendered & hence the api in it is getting called again

I tried by setting `enableReinitialize={false}` but nothing works

Is it possible to prevent this rerendering of the component(`Rerenderedcomponent`) on formik field update

PS:- The component should remain inside formik tag only

Comment: why did you write `return (` inside JSX?  i guess it works but it will consider `return` as a string. Where does `values` comes from?

Comment: This is not the exact code, just an algo of what I am trying to do, the values & setFieldValue variables I am gettiing from formik you can check out here https://formik.org/docs/overview

Answer (score 0):

I prevent the component rerendering inside formik using the below workaround:

Created a new component say (Hello.js) & included the conditonal rendering(that was inside formik tag previously) inside it, like an example shown below

```
function Hello({show})
{
return(
<>
{show &&  <Text>Hello</Text>}
</>
)
}
export default React.memo(Hello);
```

Now I just imported & use the `Hello.js` component inside formik as shown below

```
<formik 
  initialValue={{
    "show":false
  }}>
  return (
    <button name="showbtn" onclick={setFieldValue("show",true)}/>
     <Hello show={values?.show}/>  // Hello.js component
    <Rerenderedcomponent />  //this will not rerender now 
  )
</formik>
```

Now since the component is already mounted into the DOM the rerendering will not occur on show value change

Answer (score 0):

Also there is one another workaround to resolve this issue just by changing the order of components inside formik tag

```
<formik 
  initialValue={{
    "show":false
  }}>
  return (
    <button name="showbtn" onclick={setFieldValue("show",true)}/>

<Rerenderedcomponent />  //placed above conditional rendering
{  values?.show ?     
     (
       <Text>Hello</Text>
     ) : 
    null
}
```

)

I moved the rerendered component above the conditional rendering & it resolved the issue

Answer (score 0):

To prevent `RerenderedComponent` from contacting the api every time. You must define a state in the parent component and pass it to child component:

```
const [apiData, setApiData] = useState(); // <===

return (
    <Formik
        initialValues={{ show: false }}
        onSubmit={(values) => {}}
    >
        {({ setValues, values }) => (
            <Form>
                <button
                    type="button"
                    onClick={() => setValues({ show: !values.show })}
                >
                    {values.show ? "hide" : "show"}
                </button>
                {values.show && (
                    <Rerenderedcomponent apiData={apiData} setApiData={setApiData} /> // <===
                )}
            </Form>
        )}
    </Formik>
);
```

And in the child component, you can check the existence of apiData and communicate with the api if needed:

```
function Rerenderedcomponent({ apiData, setApiData }) {
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!apiData) {
            // fetch data here ...
            setApiData('<response>');
        }
    }, []);
    return null; // A Redact component must return a value
}
```